# Do the MILA missions ever end?

Tags: fallout-4

Tinker Tom keeps giving me these missions - I do seem to be making 'some' kind of progress as he tells me now we have good coverage of the wasteland.... and then tells me he has another for me to setup.

Do they ever end or is this another infinite quest setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, these missions eventually end. There are 11 Weathervane missions where you place MILAs.  The order in which you receive them however, is randomized.

See [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Weathervane_(quest)) for a list of the 11 locations.  Note that these may be spoilers to you, as they give you an indication as to how to reach the platforms and of other notable loot.